# jquery form plugin with hash change

Tags: forms, jquery, fragment-identifier

currently im having problems with the jquery form plugin. Part of this because i need to change the hash value on form submit. Heres the basic of what im doing:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
$('#search').ajaxForm({
target: '#pageContent',

success: function()  {
$('#pageContent'); //this is all i need to 'ajaxify' this form
var hash = 'query='+encodeURI(document.getElementById('query').value);
window.location.hash = hash;
}
});
});
```

Now what happens is i am able to change the hash value but my form no longer 'ajaxify's itself and instead i just get a blank page..

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Moar jQuery: `document.getElementById('query').value` -> `$('#query').val()`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since no-one had a suitable answer i managed to hack my implementation of jquery.history.js to allow searching via ajax.. heres the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// bind form using ajaxForm 
$('#search1').ajaxForm({ 
    // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
    target: '#pageContent', 

    // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
    success: function() { 
        $('#pageContent'); 
        var hash = '#search.php?term='+($('#query').val()+'&submit=Submit').replace(/ /g, '+');
        update(window.location.hash = hash);
    } 

});
```

});

i also replaced the spaces in the search to include `+` signs.. maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an actual hash, denoted by `#`:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  $('#search').ajaxForm({
    target: '#pageContent',    
    success: function() {
      var hash = '#query='+encodeURI($('#query').val());
      window.location.hash = hash;
    }
  });
});
```